# How do I get Angular2 to work with Flexbox

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to create an application using Angular2 and angular2-material components.

I am trying to create a workbench type container which contains a collection of cards.  I am trying to use flexbox to layout the children however it seems that my workbench component will not react to using any flexbox attributes.

Do I have to reference flexbox in the index page, or the component (I thought Angular2 was built upon flexbox) or anywhere else?

The only code I have referencing flexbox at the moment is in my workbench html template:

```
<div layout="row" >
  <div flex="100">
   <ew-text></ew-text>
  </div>
  <div flex="100">
    <ew-check></ew-check>
  </div>
  <div flex="100">
    <ew-check></ew-check>
  </div>
  <div flex="100">
    <ew-check></ew-check>
  </div>
  <div flex="100">
    <ew-text></ew-text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for looking ;)

Comment: What Angular2 Material components? What version? What component?

Comment: I am using the latest release of angular2-material

https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: The component I am creating begins with a div and resides within md-sidenav-layout

Comment: I had a brief look at Angular2 Material docs and source and it doesn't look like it applies any styles to your custom HTML. I think you will have to create CSS like explained in https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ yourself until there are some material-layout styles provided by Angular2 Material.

Comment: Thanks Gunter this has answered my question!